# A way to turn off the DASK

Tags: dask

I'm a new user of DASK. I have a code in which I use DASK for some parallelizations. Is there some easy way, like a flag, for example, to run the code with DASK off, that is, in serial?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html#configuring-the-schedulers)

You can set the scheduler to be the single-thread, in-process one, known as "sync" (or "single-threaded") within a context block:

```
with dask.config.set(scheduler='sync'):
    # do stuff
```

or until further notice

```
dask.config.set(scheduler='sync')
# do stuff
```